# ajax using jquery and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a input field with id age.
I am trying to pass this age and some other values from other input fields using ajax as follows-

```
var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
var wpm = document.getElementById('wpm').value;
var sex = document.getElementById('sex').value;
var queryString = "?age=" + age ;

queryString +=  "&wpm=" + wpm + "&sex=" + sex;
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax-example.php" + queryString, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); 
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax-example.php" + queryString, true);
```

so in my javascript part of my html document if i write

```
var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
```

the program executes perfectly.

But if i write this instead of the above statement -

```
var age =$('#age').val();
```

My age value is not passed

So my question is what is the differnece between the statements

```
var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
var age =$('#age').val();
```

Comment: 'document.getElementById('age').value;' is using pure javascript and '$('#age').val()' is using jquery library. Your jquery library must not be included if its not working

Comment: The second example is using jQuery. For it to work you need to have included the jQuery.js library in your page. Have you at checked the console for any errors?

Comment: Thank You so much bro :)
I included JQuery.js and it worked :)
stackoverflow FTW :D

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```
 var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
```

Jquery

```
var age =$('#age').val();
```

If `$("#age").val()` is not working then odds are that you don't have the libraries loaded for jquery at all

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
```

Is for the latest jquery libraries. If you load that library into your page than all jquery scripts and functions should work which I'm fairly positive ajax is a jquery function so you'll want to do that